# Convergence to exponential

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n\to1$, is it true that $(a_n+\frac{x}{n})^n\to e^{\alpha+x}$, where $\alpha$ is some constant. For example, if we take $a_n=1+1/n$ then clearly $(a_n+\frac{x}{n})^n\to e^{1+x}$, is that the case for all such $a_n$?

Answer (score 1):

No: if $a_n=1+n^{-1/2}$ then $n^{-1/2}$ wins over $\frac xn$ and the sequence diverges. For a simple estimate, consider that Bernoulli's inequality $$\left(1+n^{-1/2}+\frac xn\right)^n\ge 1+n^{1/2}+x$$ holds as soon as $n^{-1/2}+\frac xn> -1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left(a_n+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(a_n+\frac{x}{n}\right)}$$

and

$$n\log\left(a_n+\frac{x}{n}\right)=\frac{\log a_n+\log\left(1+\frac{x}{na_n}\right)}{\frac1n}
=n\log a_n+\frac x{a_n}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{na_n}\right)}{\frac x{na_n}}$$

then since

$$\frac x{a_n}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{na_n}\right)}{\frac x{na_n}}\to x$$

all depends upon the term

$$n\log a_n$$

which may converges or not to $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

For example we have

$$a_n=1+\frac1n \implies \alpha = n\log a_n=\log \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \to \log e=1$$

but for

$$a_n=1+\frac1{\log n} \implies \alpha = n\log a_n=\log \left(1+\frac1{\log n}\right)^n \to \infty$$